# IOS: create a little encyclopedia

Tags: ios, database, xcode, core-data

I want to create an app where I have a table view and when I select a row where inside is written a name (at example "house") it give me in a textView the explanation of its meaning. What's the approach to do this app? I sould use a database as core data? but what's the way to take the text for every word? Can I use txt file or what? Can you help me?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for application design, or information on how to write the whole app.  That question is a bit broad for this site's format.  You're actually asking us to do the design/planning phase for you, which on many projects is the most time-consuming part of app development.

Comment: no no .... I understand that the desing/planning phase is time expensive, and I don't want that someone tell me ho to project this app; I want just an advice to understand how organize this app and where I can take data to have a long string for the explanation of a word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the data locally, I'd go either for core db, or xml file, depending on the kind of data. When you create a project in XCode with core data enabled, you can see how the crud is done.

Comment: ok but in my app I have much text, where I can take this text? from what type of file?

Comment: I'll say the same thing, you easily create an xml file with <Comment></Comment> and put as much text as you want, OR you can insert that data in the database. It's up to what you are more comfortable with, what'll be easier for your current vision, and what would be more maintainable. If you have a database, it might be easier to maintain, but again you can easily achieve that with XML as well.